# How to calculate expected value of matrix norms of $A^TA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, normed-spaces, random-matrices

Let $A$ be a random $m$ by $n$ rectangular sign matrix, chosen uniformly at random, with $m < n$. To be clear,  $A$ is a matrix whose entries are chosen from $\{1,-1\}$.

Let $B = A^T A$.  We know, for example, that $B$ is a square and symmetric $n$ by $n$ matrix with all its  diagonal entries equal to $m$ exactly.   I am trying to learn how to calculate the expected [Frobenius](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html) and [spectral norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpectralNorm.html)  of $B$.  We can assume both $m$ and $n$ are large if that helps give a good bound or estimate.

> How can you calculate $\mathbb{E}(||B||_F)$ and
>   $\mathbb{E}(||B||_2)$?

The expected Frobenius norm of $B$ is defined to be

$$
\mathbb{E}(||B||_F)=\mathbb{E}\left(\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n |b_{ij}|^2}\right)
$$

where $b_{ij}$ are the elements of $B$.

The expected spectral norm of $B$ is defined to be

$$
\mathbb{E}(||B||_2)= \mathbb{E}\left(\max_{|x|_2 \ne 0}\frac{|Bx|_2}{|x|_2}\right).
$$

---

Cross-posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222994/how-to-calculate-expected-value-of-matrix-norms-of-ata now.  I will update this question if anything substantive is added there.

Comment: what is definition of $\mathbb{E}(||B||_F)$?

Comment: @RaziehNoori https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm

Comment: since B is symmetric, its matrix norm is the maximum eigen value...

Comment: There is now also a MO copy of this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/222994/how-to-calculate-expected-value-of-matrix-norms-of-ata @felipa I think the fact that you posted it on MO should be mentioned on your post. See [this recommendation on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088).

Comment: Will it be helpful to do it with a normal distribution instead uniform?

Comment: @Gil Do mean for $A$ which is currently a $\{-1,1\}$ matrix? I don't know any bounds that would relate one to the other but maybe they exist?

Comment: @felipa, If the diagonal entries are exactly $m$ (which is true), doesn't it mean the expectation for the Frobenius norm will always be $\sqrt{(mn)}$? (the variance will clearly be $0$...). What am I missing?

Comment: @Gil As commented below, this is the Frobenius norm of $A$, not $B$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a try. The matrix entries are Bernoulli random variables, that get a value of $\pm 1$. A Bernoulli random variable is zero mean subgaussian variable with finite moments.

If we define $\lambda = m/n$, then for large values of $m,n$:

$\Vert A \Vert_2 \rightarrow \sqrt{n}\left(1+\sqrt\lambda \right)$

and therefore, $\Vert B \Vert_2 \rightarrow n\left(1+\sqrt\lambda \right)^2$

Asymptotically, $\Vert A \Vert_2 = \sqrt m+\sqrt n$ and $\Vert B \Vert_2=(\sqrt m + \sqrt n)^2$.

Here is the reference I used:
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/rv-rectangular-matrices.pdf

Another good reference is "Smallest singular value of random matrices and geometry of random polytopes" by Litvak et. al.

I tried it in MATLAB and it seems to be working well:

A = sign(rand(1e5,10)-0.5);
c = 10/1e5;

sqrt(1e5)*(1+sqrt(c))

ans =

319.3900

norm(A)

ans =

318.8748

Now, for the Frobenius norm. The goal is to compute for start $\mathbb{E}(\Vert B \Vert_F^2)$. Let's divide it for two cases:

1) The diagonal part: very simple, since the elements are always $m$ the total contribution of the diagonal is $nm^2$.

2) The off-diagonal part ($i \neq j$): note that $\mathbb{E}(b_{ij})=0$ for $i\neq j$, so using the facts the RVs are iid, we get: $\mathbb{E}(b_{ij}^2)=\mathrm{Var}(\sum_k a_{ik}a_{jk})=\sum_k \mathrm{Var}(a_{ik}a_{jk})=m$, (again, for $i \neq j$). All in all, $n(n-1)$ off-diagonal elements.

Summing it all gives: $\mathbb{E}(\Vert B\Vert_F^2)=nm^2+n(n-1)m=nm^2+n^2m-mn$.

Using Bernstein's inequality for Bernoulli random variables with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, for large matrix the variance decays exponentially, and therefore $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(\Vert B\Vert_F^2)} \rightarrow \mathbb{E}(\Vert B\Vert_F)$

Comment: I think the Frobenius norm answer is wrong unfortunately.  Take the matrix with one row $A=(1,1,1,1)$.   $A^TA$ is a $4$ by $4$ all ones matrix with Frobenius norm 4. But your answer suggests it should be $\sqrt{1*4} = 2$.

Comment: You are right. What I wrote was on the Frobenius norm of $A$...

Comment: How have you gone from knowing $||A||_2$ to giving $||B||_2$?

Comment: If $B=A^TA$ then $\Vert B \Vert_2=\Vert A \Vert_2^2$

Comment: btw, I thought of it and computing $\mathbb{E}(\Vert B \Vert_F^2)$ should not be difficult. The question is if it is helpful or only  $\mathbb{E}(\Vert B \Vert_F)$ is interesting to you.

Comment: Thanks! There is an answer for the Frobenius norm in the linked MO answer now.  Do you mean $\mathbb{E}(\Vert B \Vert_2)$ is asymptotic to $(\sqrt m + \sqrt n)^2$?

Comment: Yes. I also added my way for the Frobenius norm, based on direct computation and basic probability.